# General Questions on Sonos Development

Tags: sonos

We are working on a project that requires a mobile application to remotely control Wi-Fi speaker. On our Analysis We found Sonos as a good one. I have some queries related to the Sonos Speaker.

1. Are the APIs available for Sonos speakers open source ?
2. Does the sonos bridge comes together with sonos play1 speakers?
3. What is the purpose of sonos bridge?
4. Is Javascript API available for Sonos speaker?
5. Can we use the airplay protocol to connect with the sonos device?
6. Is support available for developers working on Sonos APIs?
7. Has Sonos speaker been implemented in any retail store/Customers?

Answer (score 2):

1. The only published API for Sonos is here http://musicpartners.sonos.com/ most of the documentation is available without signing in.
2. This depends on any deals on going, but generally no. But a bridge is not required. http://blog.sonos.com/news/introducing-an-even-simpler-sonos
3. See the link above.  A bridge is used to improve the wireless performance for a Sonos system.
4. No.
5. No.
6. Support is available through StackOverflow where Sonos Developer Advocates will answer API related questions.
7. Not sure what you mean by implemented.  Many services have integrated with Sonos including some which are specifically designed for businesses. Sonos speakers are also used in many retail environments.